# Get most recent modification date of all the files in a directory

Tags: c#

I am a real newbie in C#, and I am trying to get the most recent modification time (LastWriteTime) for any file in a directory.

What is a simple way to get this information ?

Comment: Do you want to check files from nested folder as well or only from files from given directory?

Comment: `var time = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"c:\MyFiles").Max(file => new FileInfo(file).LastWriteTime);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simplify your code to use this approach:

```
DirectoryInfo di_source_directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\MyFolder");
FileSystemInfo[] ls_fi = di_source_directory.GetFileSystemInfos();
DateTime ts_most_recent = (ls_fi.Any() 
                 ? ls_fi.Max(fi => fi.LastWriteTime) 
                 : default(DateTime));
```

or just replace the *default(DateTime)* part with *new DateTime(.....)*

Comment: the conditional operator ?: is a nice syntax :-)

Answer (score 0):

I could retrieve the timestamp of the most recent updated file using this code, with the help of @DiplomacyNotWar:

```
DirectoryInfo di_source_directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\MyFolder");
FileSystemInfo[] ls_fi = di_source_directory.GetFileSystemInfos();
DateTime defaultTS = new DateTime(2022, 1, 1);
DateTime ts_most_recent = ls_fi.Select(fi => fi.LastWriteTime).DefaultIfEmpty(defaultTS).Max();
```

Comment: You don't need to materialise this, you can call `.Max()` without `.ToList()`. Additionally, this will throw an exception if there are no files in the directory. You probably want a `.DefaultIfEmpty(someValue)` before the `.Max()` so that you can specify a default.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar Thanks a lot for your advice. I will edit the code accordingly.

Comment: Even better, Max takes a lambda, no  need to have a Select.

Comment: @LionelHamayon this code cannot be compiled. A datetime need to be created with new, but even so, the error becomes _CS1929 'DateTime' does not contain a definition for 'DefaultIfEmpty' and the best extension method overload 'Enumerable.DefaultIfEmpty<DateTime>(IEnumerable<DateTime>, DateTime)' requires a receiver of type 'IEnumerable<DateTime>'_